# How using puppeteer in an electron window js for web scraping?

Tags: web-scraping, browser, electron, puppeteer, headless

I have an electron application where on a main screen I use react js to show the data of mixing information from two web scraping that I do through a puppeteer. But web scrapers open their process windows in a separate browser. This interrupts my main window because I have to open the browser to do the scraping. I can't hide the browser for scraping since I have to download an excel and puppeteer/selenium can't do it with the hidden browser. I want to use the Electron js browser to prevent web scraping from opening in another window. Is there any way of doing this?

I try to use puppeteer-in-electron and puppeteer-core to open the browser of the site where i scrape but i can't get it to work

Comment: "I have to download an excel and puppeteer/selenium can't do it with the hidden browser" -- are you sure? A [mcve] would be useful, because this assumption might not be true. A MCVE of "I try to use puppeteer-in-electron and puppeteer-core to open the browser of the site where i scrape but i can't get it to work" would be nice too.. It's much easier to help with your existing code than to try to rewrite it all from scratch in a way that guesses what your use case is. We don't know what site you're working with or what you're downloading.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do that by setting flag "headless": "new" for Puppeteer launch options, this will prevent new windows from opening in foreground. Actually there's an open-source project which you may be interested in, which is designed for scraping / submitting / accounts registering, etc: [OpenSubmitter](https://github.com/MoterHaker/opensubmitter). It consists of ElectronJS + Vite + Vue + Puppeteer bundle.